# Fast Out-Proc cache for ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, caching

I need suggestion for Out-Proc cache for ASP.Net application.

The `HttpRuntime.Cache` is In-Proc cache can't be shared by multi w3wp.exe processes.

I am ware that there are some of open source projects for this subject, like http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/

But the problem is --
 1. Serialization is required to store/get the cached data, which is
    slow for big object instance.
 2. Some types from ASP.Net framework are not allowed to be serialized,  like `RouteColltion` class.

Do you have any idea for a fast Out-Proc cache solution without serialization?

Comment: Why do you need to cache a RouteCollection?

Comment: What type of big object instances/trees are you using? Why are you caching a RouteCollection object? (Isn't the current RouteCollection always present in RouteTable.Tables?) Have you considered caching rendered html instead of the underlying data structures?

Comment: RouteCollection is just an example, my MVC framework is modified and the RouteCollection is loaded dynamically.  the initialization procedure takes more than 40 seconds even with Parallel loading

Comment: I need same but my concern is different. I want to query 100k objects by LinqToObject .

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is inevitable when using an out-proc cache since objects are to me transmitted form one process to another process (probably on another machine), which cannot be done without serializing objects.

However to reduce performance cost of serialization, [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) a .net based distributed caching solution provides [Compact Serialization](http://www.alachisoft.com/support/support_articles/using-ncache-compact-serialization.html) feature. Compact serialization as its name suggests provides optimized serialization of objects resulting in less number of bytes as compared to native .Net serialization. Thus reducing communication time required to transmit or receive data from out of process cache.